# PostgreSQL: Select only the first record per id based on sort order

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group, distinct-on

For the following query I need to select only the first record with the lowest shape_type value (ranges from 1 to 10). If you have any knowledge on how to easily do this is postgresql, please help. Thanks for your time.

```
select g.geo_id, gs.shape_type
from schema.geo g   
join schema.geo_shape gs on (g.geo_id=gs.geo_id)  
order by gs.shape_type asc;
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

PostgreSQL have very nice syntax for this types of queries - [distinct on](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html):

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of
>   each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The
>   DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for
>   ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is
>   unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row
>   appears first.

So your query becomes:

```
select distinct on(g.geo_id)
    g.geo_id, gs.shape_type
from schema.geo g   
    join schema.geo_shape gs on (g.geo_id=gs.geo_id)  
order by g.geo_id, gs.shape_type asc;
```

In general ANSI-SQL syntax for this (in any RDBMS with window functions and common table expression, which could be switched to subquery) would be:

```
with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over(partition by g.geo_id order by gs.shape_type) as rn,
        g.geo_id, gs.shape_type
    from schema.geo g   
        join schema.geo_shape gs on (g.geo_id=gs.geo_id)  
)
select
    geo_id, shape_type
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This is nice.  I wasnt able to figure out how to do by two fields, but I did simply just concatenate the two fields and use that as my key for the distinct on portion of the query.

Comment: @theStud54 you can `distinct on` by record type : `distinct on ((g.geo_id, g.geo_id2))` - see simple db fiddle with example - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bbbf51b8789ad3f11e476866c411fb3c

Comment: Ahhh, well thank you @roman_pekar for the comment.  This helped me fix another item in addition to this!  Saved me 40% time on my query